# Как убрать вертикальную полосу между фигурными скобками в intelijidea?

Tags: intellij-idea, pycharm, phpstorm, jetbrains, settings

Скажите пожалуйста, как убрать вертикальную полосу между фигурными скобками как на этом изображении? Спасибо.[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

Settings -> Editor -> Appearance -> Show indent quides

Comment: К сожалению это не работает

Comment: вы не указали версию IDE в которой работаете. Проверьте и другие настройки Appearance, в Intellij Idea 2022 работает